# Collision detection on a rotated Image

Tags: java, swing, rotation, collision

How would you go about detecting collision on a rotated Image in a game? I am making an asteroids game an I cannot figure out how to make the asteroids properly collide with the rotated spaceship.

Answer (score 2):

If the rotated object is one that implements the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, it may have a useful implementation of the `contains()` method.

Comment: Perhaps an existing `Shape` could be used to approximate the image's collision boundary.

Comment: @user1150769 for better help sooner edit your your questions with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In paint(), as you prepare to draw the in-motion image, check the pixel colors of the destination points and look for the target object's color(s).  The in-motion image and the target object must be, of course, different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel-perfect collision detection, ie. collision detection between images, is generally really hard to do efficiently. For that reason, it is generally a good idea to use an existing, optimized library built for that purpose.

Since you also need support for rotated images, I recommend [PoxelColl](https://github.com/Poxelcoll/Poxelcoll). It supports pixel-perfect collision detection as well as basic transformations such as scaling and rotation. It provides a Scala port, which is compatible with Java.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you using for collision boundaries of your asteroid?

Simplest might be that you can just use circles for everything and implement a circle-circle collision detection (just google it). This may not visually pleasing if your images are not very circle like.

Otherwise, if you have rotating rectangles colliding with other rotating rectangles then you'll have to implement an algorithm using [Separating Axis Theorem for 2D Rotated Rectangle Collision](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604).

Another option might be pixel perfect collision detection which is what [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9689750/879167) was talking about. A quick search turned up this forum [post](http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/40882-pixel-perfect-collision-detection-use-your-java-games.html). Proceed with caution though, this method's performance degrades with the size of your images.